# How do you clean up unused virtuemart 2 product images?

Tags: virtuemart, images

I have more than 10000 images in my images/stories/virtuemart/product/ folder. (cant even see more than 9999).

Now there are a lot of unused images piled up under the years question is :

How do you clean up unused virtuemart 2 product images, not having to go one-by-one check and delete.

Thanks,
Attila.

Answer (score 1):

The only automated way to review the active images is comparing image filenames in the database and the filenames in the image directory.

If you are working in Linux, you need some scripting hackery to compare two text files with VM image filenames versus all image filenames ... some commands like find *.jpg | grep | sort | diff ... at the end you get the list of images to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

See my free tool https://shop.st42.fr/en/products/virtuemart-media-folder-clear.htm you have 2 buttons, one to remove unused images and 1 to clear database error(missing image > products for eg.)